# i want to run js file External Scripts( JS, Jquery) Not working in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I am creating a web app frontend using ReactJS.

I have downloaded a Template from which is designed using HTML5 CSS Custom JS file and also includes some third party/vendor JS/jQuery carouFredSel, etc

i have problem on react.js when i open the page error give me on console like

```
 carouFredSel: No element found for "#mission .carousel.main ul".
```

when  the normal html and add my files java script and other file it work correctly.

i think from the react render  it render the home  after the script done ?
any help on this problem!

Comment: Mixing jQuery with tools like React or Angular is fraught with peril.  jQuery functionality binds directly to DOM elements, which in tools like React can come and go very often.  Is there a particular reason you want to use jQuery for this instead of building the functionality in React?  If using a 3rd party tool, does the vendor provide a version for React?  Does an alternate vendor provide a similar product that works with React?  If you want to use React then building your intended functionality in React is likely going to be easier to build and maintain than trying to integrate jQuery.

Comment: i know that but my company give me template with js files and want me to convert it work with react js and i have issue with the js scripts don't works!

Comment: If your employer has specifically requested that you integrate React and jQuery together (did they specifically make that a requirement?) then your first step isn't necessarily a technical one.  Whatever technical leadership you report to (architect, development lead, etc.) would need to provide guidance on how they have done that or how they expect to do that, because it's *a lot* to expect of an otherwise junior associate.  If there is no such technical leadership and that role falls to you then you would want to address that very strange requirement with whoever provided it.

Comment: In any event, there *are* ways to use jQuery with React.  The linked duplicate looks like a good starting point.  But I can't stress enough that supporting this sort of integration will generally require a strong understanding of how the two tools work.

Comment: If the component adding is isolated, eg. In it's own DIV etc, it's not too hard to do.  The main thing you do is create a container DIV inside React, and use a `ref`, don't do anything else to this DIV inside React,.  Then inside a `useEffect`, do something like -> `ref.current.innerHTML = '.,,...';  $(ref.current).carousel()`  <- or whatever method this jQuery component calls to init.   I use the this method to add all sorts of none React components, eg.  Code editors etc.

Comment: keith please can you give me example with this?

Comment: I could do, but the question has been closed, I'll do a re-open request, but it will require more than me, maybe @David could do a re-open too, the dupe is pretty old so a version using hooks might be useful for others.  The nice thing once you have wrapped a none React component, it can be re-used again & again, ..  eg I have things like `<CodeEditor value={value} onChange={....`  and it will even load and external libs etc, so from a React POV it just feels like a React component.  Oh, it just re-opened, I always thought it required more votes.. :)

Comment: i  think know it opened

Answer (score 2):

Below is an example of mixing jQuery & React.

The main thing here is that you create a DIV, then get using `React.useRef`, assign this to the DIV, inside a `useEffect` you will then have direct access to the DIV, you can then set its `innerHTML` and apply any jQuery methods to it.

Example below of a jQuery carousel, at the top, and standard React at the bottom.

> NOTE: You can of course extend this to pass props too, so the
> `innerHTML` can be made passing the image urls as an array etc.
> but will keep as is so that's its easy for others to follow.

```js
const domNode = document.getElementById('mount');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(domNode);


function Carousel() {
  const ref = React.useRef();
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const pl = 'https://albert-cyberhulk.github.io/jQuery-Carousel/example/bower_components/jquery-cccarousel/src/img/placeholder.png';
    ref.current.innerHTML = `
<div class="dynamic">
  <div class="leftDirection"></div>
  <div class="rightDirection"></div>
  <div class="slider">
      ${new Array(14).fill(
      `<div class="image"><img src="${pl}"/></div>`)}
  </div>
</div>`
    $(ref.current).ccCarousel({});
  },[]);
  return <div 
  className="galleryWrapper"
  ref={ref}></div>;
}


function App() {
  return <React.Fragment>
     <Carousel/>
     <div style={{color: 'white'}}>Above is a jQuery Carousel.</div>
     <div style={{color: 'yellow'}}>Mixed with React</div>
  </React.Fragment>
}


root.render(<App/>);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://albert-cyberhulk.github.io/jQuery-Carousel/example/bower_components/jquery-cccarousel/src/css/cc_styles.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://albert-cyberhulk.github.io/jQuery-Carousel/example/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://albert-cyberhulk.github.io/jQuery-Carousel/example/bower_components/jquery-cccarousel/src/js/cc_script.js"></script>


<div id="mount"></div>
```